# VBA code to create folders and subfolder while referencing a range of cells from column B to D?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 columns of data within Excel that I'm trying to transform into a list of folders and sub folders. Column B will be the first list of primary folders, and each entry of column C will be a sub-folder and deeper into sub folder of column D in the corresponding folder from column B.

**Column A** comprises of `.pdf` files names stored in the source destinations that needs to be transferred into the last sub-folder of the target destination.

Source & target Directory:

- Source: `C:\Users\Manzurfa\Desktop\Macro Project\Carlo Project\Order Confirmations`
- Target: `C:\Users\Manzurfa\Desktop\Macros`

Note: Source directory comprises of all the `.pdf` files. After all the folders and sub folders are create I would need the `.pdf` files transferred into the last sub folder mentioned in the target directory.

```
    A              B                       C                       D
Sales doc.        Sales Rep           Customer Name             Sold to
536460575   Carolyn Coulter     A STEP AHEAD FOOTWEAR INC       108845
536460718   Carolyn Coulter     A STEP AHEAD FOOTWEAR INC       108845
536810226   Carolyn Coulter     A STEP AHEAD FOOTWEAR INC       108845
538391188   Carolyn Coulter     A STEP AHEAD FOOTWEAR INC       108845
536281822   Carolyn Coulter     ALPHA COMFORT SHOES INC         157808
```

---

```
Sub MakeFolders()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer
    Set Rng = Selection

    maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
    maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count

    For c = 2 To maxCols
        r = 2
        Do While r <= maxRows
            If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c))
                On Error Resume Next
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    Next c
End Sub
```

Any help at would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub Tester()

    Const SRC_FOLDER = "C:\Users\Manzurfa\Desktop\Macro Project\Carlo Project\Order Confirmations\"
    Const DEST_FOLDER = "C:\Users\Manzurfa\Desktop\Macros"

    Dim Rng As Range, fPath, fName
    Dim maxRows As Long, maxCols As Long, r As Long, c As Long

    Set Rng = Selection
    maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
    maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count

    'assuming the first row in ther selection is the headers...
    '  otherwise, start at 1
    For r = 2 To maxRows
        fPath = DEST_FOLDER '<<set starting point
        For c = 2 To maxCols
            fPath = fPath & "\" & Rng.Cells(r, c) '<<build next level
            If Len(Dir(fPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir fPath
        Next c
        'create file name
        fName = Right("0000000000" & Rng.Cells(r, 1).Value, 10) & ".pdf"
        'copy to fpath
        FileCopy SRC_FOLDER & fName, fPath & "\" & fName
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you @Tim Williams.  I appreciate you sitting down to write out a solution to my question despite my lack of understanding of VBA.

I tested it but It doesn't seem to create any folder/subfolders in the target destination. Would you suggest I change my destination folder?

Comment: What *does* it do?

Comment: @  Tim Williams , When I hit the F8 button to test the macro it keeps looping over from top to bottom, with no folders or subfolders in the destination folders. 

Also, the "play button" does not work. As in, when I try to run the macro, it does nothing.

Comment: And you're selecting the full range of data before you run it?

Comment: Oh! I didn't select the full range of data before running the code. I tried doing that and it returned an Error message:Run-time error '53': File not found.

Highlighted line with error: 

FileCopy SRC_FOLDER & fName, fPath & "\" & fName"

Comment: I changed the source path and noticed that there's an error with the line below now.

If Len(Dir(fPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir fPath

Comment: I'm happy to help you get this working but you will need to be a bit more explicit than "there's an error" - what is the error message you get?  If you add `Debug.Print fPath` just before the line that errors what is the output (it will show up in the immediate pane of the VBeditor - Ctrl+G to show if not already visible)?

Comment: It worked brilliantly. I had a file name that had "/" which is why it threw an error. You're awesome. Thank you so much for having helped me with this.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working